Compile Azure Functions within monorepo projects
I tried to write an Azure Functions in a monorepo project written in Typescript, following the Azure Functions guide.
However, when running $ pnpm start to run the azure functions locally, it showed error about the import path:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Worker was unable to load entry point "dist/src/functions/example.js": 
Cannot find module '/workspace/depot/packages/prisma/node_modules/data/entity' 
imported from /workspace/depot/packages/prisma/task.js

I am sure that there is something wrong with the module resolution of these projects, but no idea where the issue is and how to fix it. Because of the requirements of azure function tools (or may not), the function file has to be in ES module, and this requires the .js extension of the import path for all its dependencies? But the import paths in the generated JS codes in prisma and data projects are still in Typescript style. Any idea how to fix it?
Btw, any idea how to make the import path in apps/worker/src/functions/example.ts cleaner? I think it would be much better to keep 'prisma/task' rather than 'prisma/dist/task.js'.
More details below. Let me know if anything else is needed to solve this issue.
Here is the project structure:
.
├── apps
│   └── worker
|       ├── src/functions
|       |   └── example.ts
|       ├── package.json
|       └── tsconfig.json
├── packages
│   ├── prisma
|   |   ├── client
|   |   |   ├── index.js
|   |   |   ...
|   |   |
|   |   ├── prisma.schema
|   |   ├── task.ts
|   |   ├── package.json
|   |   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── data
|       ├── entity.ts
|       ├── package.json
|       └── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.json


The project packages/prisma imports project packages/data, and the apps/worker imports packages/prisma to connect to the database:
/// apps/worker/src/functions/example.ts

// This module won't be found.
import { getTask } from 'prisma/task';

// This works.
import { getTask } from 'prisma/dist/task.js';

/// packages/prisma/task.ts

// I need to keep this because it is also used by other projects.
import { Entity } from 'data/entity';

Generated packages/prisma/task.ts js code:
/// packages/prisma/dist/task.js

// Module import path is not changed.
import { Entity } from 'data/entity';

Here is the package.json file for worker project:
/// apps/worker/package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
  "type": "module",  // required by azure function tools?
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "prestart": "pnpm run clean && pnpm run build",
    "start": "func start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prisma": "workspace:*",
    "data": "workspace:*",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x",
    ...
  }
}


Here are the tsconfig.ts files:
/// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  }
}

/// apps/worker/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../../packages/data" },
    { "path": "../../packages/prisma" }
  ]
}


/// packages/prisma/tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.d.ts", "**/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "client/**/*", "dist"],
  "references": [{ "path": "../data" }]
}

/// packages/data/tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}


For the packages/prisma/client, it is generated by the prisma from the prisma.schema file, and it should not be re-compiled by tsc and we can just copy/paste it to the dist/ directory I guess?

The apps/worker project uses ES modules ("type": "module" in package.json), which requires explicit .js extensions in import paths post-compilation.

add  scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTrigger1/example.js" in function.json

The error ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND indicates that the Node.js runtime cannot find the specified module.
To resolve it, add "scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTrigger1/example.js" in function.json.
In example.js, ensure the import path for data/entity :
import entity from '../../data/entity';


Sample Prisma schema:
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  email     String   @unique
  name      String?
  posts     Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  author    User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int?
}



Refer this link to create and deploy a Prisma-based Node.js REST API to Azure Functions
Refer this Prisma Documentation for Prisma Client API.
Use npx prisma migrate deploy to apply all pending database migrations in a production environment.


Then run func host start


The function js code can be found, and what could not be found is the import 'data/entity' in packages/prisma/task.ts.

Glad to know function js is code is found. To resolve data/entity in tsconfig.json, you can add a compilerOptions entry for paths to set up the alias:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",  // Ensure this points to the root of your monorepo
    "paths": {
      "data/*": ["packages/data/*"]
    }
  }
}```
This will tell TypeScript that whenever it encounters an import like `import { Entity } from 'data/entity' `, it should resolve it to `packages/data/entity.ts `.
